# Unable to build new Openfire plugin

Tags: java, android, xmpp, openfire

As I want to make a plugin I have followed these steps:

**(I am using openfire source in eclipse)**

1. I copied a inbuilt plugin(ex. subscription or presence plugin) from openfire **src/plugins**  and then edited .java and plugin.xml files.(I am editing existing one because of using exact structure of openfire plugin)

[image]

3. I past this new plugin with name "myplugin" in **src/plugins**.
4. in **ant view** of **build.xml** I run **clear** (to clear target and work folder).
5. now I run **plugin** and also **plugins** in **ant view** to build my new plugin.

now jar of all inbuilt plugins is made in target/plugin folder but **no jar for my new plugin.**

So what I am missing..Why I am unable to build my new plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out , I needed to add myplugin in build path ,then run plugins in ant view.